# How to switch between test code and production code in python?

Tags: python

I have a project that is constantly undergoing development. I have installed a release of the project in my python distribution's `site-packages` directory using the `setup.py` script for the project.

However, when I make changes to the project I would like my test scripts to find the files that are under the project's directory and not those that it finds in `site-packages`. What is the proper way to do this? I only know of one approach which is to modify the search path in the test script itself using `sys.path`, but then it means that I cannot use the same scripts to test the "installed" version of my codes without editing the `sys.path` again.

Comment: Two words: virtual envs.

Comment: @freakish I know about virtual envs and have been exploring on how i can make the best use of them. Any suggestions on the work flow? Are you suggesting to use a virtual env for the project's development, but use the main python distribution for system-wide installation?

Comment: I suggest using virtual env with `python setup.py develop` (see dm03514's answer). That should be all you need. No need to ever install anything system-wide.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking but you could use

`python setup.py develop` to create a develop version of your project

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode

> Under normal circumstances, the distutils assume that you are going to
>   build a distribution of your project, not use it in its “raw” or
>   “unbuilt” form. If you were to use the distutils that way, you would
>   have to rebuild and reinstall your project every time you made a
>   change to it during development.
>
> Another problem that sometimes comes up with the distutils is that you
>   may need to do development on two related projects at the same time.
>   You may need to put both projects’ packages in the same directory to
>   run them, but need to keep them separate for revision control
>   purposes. How can you do this?
>
> Setuptools allows you to deploy your projects for use in a common
>   directory or staging area, but without copying any files. Thus, you
>   can edit each project’s code in its checkout directory, and only need
>   to run build commands when you change a project’s C extensions or
>   similarly compiled files. You can even deploy a project into another
>   project’s checkout directory, if that’s your preferred way of working
>   (as opposed to using a common independent staging area or the
>   site-packages directory).

Answer (score 1):

Use "[Editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)" package installation like:

```
pip install -e path/to/SomeProject
```

Assuming we are in the same directory with setup.py, the command will be:

```
pip install -e .
```